# Artifactory: Inconsistent number of builds reported

Tags: artifactory

When I select an artifact in the tree view, go to builds and select "Used By" I get a different number than what is returned when I query the API for "Builds for Dependency".

`https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildsforDependency`

What is the difference between these two?